# Reducing code duplication in a tic-tac-toe implementation

Tags: c

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game in C and my function checkwinner() has a lot of code duplication in the form of if-statements.

```
void checkwinner(void){
     if(square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3]){
         printresult(square[2]);
     }
     else if(square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6]){
         printresult(square[5]);
     }
     else if(square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9]){
         printresult(square[8]);
     }
     else if(square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7]){
         printresult(square[4]);
     }
     else if(square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8]){
         printresult(square[5]);
     }
     else if(square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9]){
         printresult(square[6]);
     }
     else if(square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9]){
         printresult(square[5]);
     }
     else if(square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7]){
         printresult(square[5]);
     }
}
```

The array called square[] contains either the character 'X' or 'O'. So the function compares the rows, columns and diagonals and check if the characters match.

Is there a way to reduce the code-duplication to make the code more compact?

Comment: For code that works, and all that's wanted is a *review* then please post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is not up to the codereview quality yet...

Comment: Code review must only be use for production code but this is still off topic for SO.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worthwhile to read [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292380/tic-tac-toe-program-in-c-winning-conditions-not-working) for more ideas

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP is not asking for a general review. OP is asking for how to reduce a specific piece of code. I think this question fits here.

Comment: If you use more `()` you can stop worrying about operator precedence.

Comment: You also need to check if 3 squares are not empty. This is not a winning combination.

Answer (score 1):

Like Angen said, it is good with a match function:

```
bool match(int x, int y, int z){
    return square[x] == square[y] && square[y] == square[z];
}
```

However, I would also consider rewriting this like this. I assume your `square` is a `char` array, but it works with `int` too. Also, note that you need to check empty cells.

```
/* Returns the winner on match, and otherwise 0 */
char match(int x, int y, int z){
    if(square[x] != 'X' && square[x] != 'O')
        return 0;
    if (square[x] == square[y] && square[y] == square[z])
        return square[x];
    returns 0;
}
```

After that, you could check for three cases separately. Maybe this is overkill for a small tic tac toe, but I show it anyway. The idea translates well to bigger applications.

```
char matchRows() {
    int row=1;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
         char c=match(row+i, row+3+i, row+6+i);
         if(c)
             return c;
    }
    return 0;
}

char matchColumns() {
    int column=1;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
         char c=match(column+i, column+1+i, column+2+i);
         if(c)
             return c;
    }
    return 0;
}

char matchDiagonals() {
    char c;
    if(c=match(1,5,9))
        return c;
    if(c=match(3,5,7))
        return c;
    return 0;
}
```

And then you could write `checkwinner` like this:

```
char checkWinner() {
    char c;
    if(c=matchRows()) 
        return c;
    if(c=matchColumns()) 
        return c;
    if(c=matchDiagonals())
        return c;
    return c;            
}
```

And the then I'd add a new function that takes over responsibilities from the previous `checkWinner`:

```
void printWinner() {
    char c=checkWinner();
    if(c)
        printResult(c);
}
```

Maybe this will not make the code more compact when counting total lines, but it is definitely better design and each individual functionality is more compact. Also, as you may notice, I separate functionality so that a function does not both print and handle the logic about how to calculate a winner.

I added [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) to your functions. That makes code easier to read.

Comment: thanks for the help, decided to go with this to check for a win
    int winningSquares[8][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9},{1,5,9},{3,5,7}};

Comment: @klutt Nice! I upvoted it! But one more thing is needed:  `return (square[x] !=' ');` in `match` function. 3 empty squares cannot win.

Comment: @sg7 Thanks. I fixed that bug.

Comment: i intialized square to char* square[10] =  {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'}; to avoid that

Comment: @tomoswizzard While that's not a bad thing, it is in general a good thing to instead (or also) to make functions assume as little as possible and do error checking. `assert` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

you can write function like this

```
bool match(int x, int y, int z){
    return square[x] == square[y] && square[y] == square[z];
}
```

and then

```
void checkwinner(void){
         if(match(1,2,3)){
         printresult(square[2]);
         }
         else if(match(4,5,6)){
         printresult(square[5]);
         } ...
```

you can move printresult into match function

```
bool match(int x, int y, int z){
        if(square[x] == square[y] && square[y] == square[z]){
             printresult(square[y]);
              return true;
        }
    return false;
    }
```

and then have something like if your function has nothing else to do

```
  void checkwinner(void){
             if(match(1,2,3)){
                 return;
             }
             if(match(4,5,6)){
                   return;
             } ...
```

Comment: Iterate through a const 8*3 array of square-numbers?

Comment: Yes thats what I decided to do, very nice stuff. @martin

Comment: and thanks for the help angen :) match function was very nice